# Is better to validate before a process, or just throws an exception?

Tags: language-agnostic, error-handling

Consider this code:

```
x = Repo.GetX(13);
Services.Process(x);
```

I could check that x is null before processing it, or I could have Services.Process() throws an exception if X is null and use a try/catch block.

Which method is preferable?

(Or should I do both, just in the exceptional case that x becomes null somehow from the point of its retrieval to processing it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to decide between:

```
x = Repo.GetX(13);
try {
    Services.Process(x);
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    System.err.println('x is NULL');
}
```

or

```
x = Repo.GetX(13);
if (x != NULL) {
    Services.Process(x);
} else {
    System.err.println('x is NULL');
}
```

Then be aware that *they don't mean the same thing*. The first one catches *any* NullPointerException thrown by `Process`. The second one only handles the case where `x` itself is NULL - if `Process` does `x.foo().bar()`, and `x.foo()` returns NULL, it isn't handled.

You should decide between the two based on what errors you can handle.

In the case where `Services.Process` is documented to throw NullPointerException if and only if `x` is NULL, so that (assuming we believe the documentation) the two do mean the same thing, then I'd do the second one. That way, if the documentation is lies, and there's a bug in `Services.Process` that makes it throw in some other situation, then we will not erroneously handle/report the exception as though `x` were NULL when in fact it is not.

So, catch and suppress an exception in two situations:

1. You know what (kind of thing) caused the error, and you know that you can handle that situation and continue regardless.
2. To protect some fairly outer level of code, like an event loop, from unexpected faults in the program or the environment. Ideally this should result in extensive logging, because either the system has failed to do what you expected (perhaps due to lack of resources or unmet dependencies), or else there's a bug in someone's code somewhere.

Don't catch just because you know *one* situation that could cause the exception, and can handle that, when the same exception could be thrown for other reasons. I suppose you could do:

```
x = Repo.GetX(13);
try {
    Services.Process(x);
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    if (x == NULL) {
        System.err.println('x is NULL');
    } else {
        throw;
    }
}
```

But that seems to me needlessly verbose in this case: since we can check in advance whether `x` is null, we might as well. There are cases, though, where you catch an exception because it's impossible or just silly to try to predict in advance whether it will occur or not:

```
String s = Rep.GetString(13);
try {
    f = Float.parseFloat(s);
    System.out.println('is a number');
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
    System.out.println('not a number');
}
```

We *could* check whether `s` is a valid number before calling `parseFloat`, but that would basically be doing the same work twice - checking a string is a valid float is pretty much the same as actually converting it. So it makes sense to catch this exception - we know what it means, we know what to do about it, we couldn't realistically have prevented it from happening.

(Or you could use DecimalFormat.parse, which doesn't throw at all)

Answer (score 1):

As usual the correct answer for this kind of problem is: It depends.

The best way if possible is to define a boundary where this kind of check is performed. Everything inside the boundary can rely on everything being nicely initialized. If still a NULL sneaks in, blowing up with a NPE is very appropriate.

In general checking preconditions before trying to perform actual work makes for much cleaner code.

If you can't establish these boundaries in your system, the question is: what happens when x is NULL and the resulting exception is not handled, what are your options when you don't handle it?

In many cases you can't do much about it anyway and then it is just fine to let the exception go up the call stack up to the ui (or service interface or whatever).

But sometimes calling process with a null argument will destroy a piece of hardware, kill a patient or be otherwise really nasty. In that case: check right before the potential harmful action.

Answer (score 0):

Far better to check. Exception handling is generally expensive.

Comment: As long as this code doesn't run in a huge loop, performance should not be considered. If it does run in a tight loop performance tests should be done and based on those the implementation adapted.

Comment: Exception handling is generally expensive *when the "exceptional" condition is common*.  If it happens one time out of a thousand, it can actually be faster to skip the check and let the exception be thrown.  As another answer stated, *it depends*.  There are other things to worry about here besides performance.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling should be used to handle exceptions.

If you thing **x** should never be null use a try/catch statement. If **x** will in some occasions be null use and if statement.